# Flutter IOS App Crashes After Google Maps Loads

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

**I have a flutter app that works fine on android / web but when i try to run in IOS simulator it crashes when i load google maps. I'm running the macpro-m1 chip btw....**

**Here is the flutter doctor output -**

```
 [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/wizeguy/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (2 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/wizeguy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPod touch (7th generation) (mobile) • B9CD8BF0-2F3C-49D6-A73F-F4BAE6ED2EF5 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                         • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      102.0.5005.115

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

**Here is the appdelegate setup --**

```
 import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("abcdefghu123345") // <-- i have real key in my code
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

**Here is the error logs from Android Studio --**

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      _PhoneNumberInput.sendSMS (package:juggy/screens/phoneNumberInput.dart:72:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
Lost connection to device.
```

Code Snippet --

```
sendSMS() async{

var data = convert.json.encode({
  'number': "+1$phoneNumber",
});

var requestHeaders = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

var url = Uri.parse(
    'https://us-central1-sonic-strains.cloudfunctions.net/app/api/twilioVerifyandSendCode');

// Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
// we need to verify code via sms
// so just change the ui back if bad request

var response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: requestHeaders);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

print("");
print("");
print("");
print("");
 print("Calling  toggle pin field");
 await widget.togglePinField();

 print("Calling  toggle map field");
 return widget.toggleMapField();


} else {
  print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  print("");
  print("your error for the sendSMS");
  print(response);

  // show the error & change the ui back if bad request


}
```

}

Just to recap

1. The app on IOS does not load the map but on web , android, etc the map loads fine.
2. The function that inits the map is called sendSMS which sends a code to the user, after successful authentication a function called toggleMap() is fired which changes the UI.
3. I'm getting an error that says the sendSMS() was called on null. I looked into this on stack but nothing I found nothing relevant to my issue.

**Here is the UI code that accepts the SMS prior to changing th UI to map view --**

```
String validatePhone(number) {
RegExp PhoneRule =
RegExp(r'^\d{10}$');

if (PhoneRule.hasMatch(number)) {
  setState(() {
    phoneError = '';
    phoneNumber = number;

  });
  return phoneError;
} else {
  setState(() {
    phoneError = 'Enter Correct Phone Number';

  });
  return phoneError;
}
```

}

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                 const Text(
                      'Juggy',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 40,
                          color: Colors.teal),
                    ),
                  SizedBox(width: 84, height: 90, child: GameWidget(game: game)),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 90,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value){
                          setState((){
                            phoneNumber = value;
                            widget.changePhoneNumber(value);
                          });},
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        maxLength: 10,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter Phone Number',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        controller: _phoneController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (validatePhone(value) == "") {
                            return null;
                          }
                          return phoneError;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      height: isProcessing ? 45 : 40,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width * 0.4,
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: isProcessing
                            ? null
                            : () async {
                          if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
                            return sendSMS();
                          }
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.phone, size: 18),
                        label: isProcessing
                            ? Container(
                            height: 30,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ))
                            : const Text("Send Code"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: _PhoneNumberInput.sendSMS (package:juggy/screens/phoneNumberInput.dart:72:34)
What's in this line?

Comment: That's the code snippet I put above. SendSms() is the function inside of the phoneNumberInput file.

Answer (score 0):

Change `_PhoneNumberInput.sendSMS`  to

```
if(_PhoneNumberInput != null)
{
  _PhoneNumberInput.sendSMS(); 
}
```

Comment: There Is already a check against the phone number before the sms function is inited, see new  ui code above

Comment: why are you returning a method here `if (_key.currentState!.validate()) { return sendSMS();}` instead of `return sendSMS()` just try using `sendSMS();`

Comment: What does the form validation have to do with the SMS function . Again the sendSMS function runs and the problem arises when the toggleMap() is fired inside of the sendSMS(). So after i enter in the correct sms code the map is supposed to show but instead crashes

Comment: Isn't the error sendSms called on null? Or something else?